# connection with nodejs and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have this todo list app from "https://codingthesmartway.com/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-1/" which has MongoDB database so I'm trying to change it in MySQL but I'm having a pretty hard time with it.

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import CreateTodo from "./components/create-todo.component";
import EditTodo from "./components/edit-todo.component";
import TodosList from "./components/todos-list.component";
import logo from "./logo.png";

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var connection = require('./backend/config/connection');
var routes = require('./backend/controllers/routes');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

connection.init();
routes.configure(app);
var server = app.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});




class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
              <img src={logo} width="30" height="30" alt="CodingTheSmartWay.com" />
            </a>
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Aftab Todo App</Link>
            <div className="collpase navbar-collapse">
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="navbar-item">
                  <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Todos</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="navbar-item">
                  <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Todo</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <br/>
          <Route path="/" exact component={TodosList} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditTodo} />
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateTodo} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

}
```

create-todo.cpmopnent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class CreateTodo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeTodoSerialno = this.onChangeTodoSerialno.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTodoDescription = this.onChangeTodoDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTodoResponsible = this.onChangeTodoResponsible.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTodoPriority = this.onChangeTodoPriority.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            todo_Serial_no: '',
            todo_description: '',
            todo_responsible: '',
            todo_priority: '',
            todo_completed: false
        }
    }

    onChangeTodoSerialno(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_Serial_no: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTodoDescription(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_description: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTodoResponsible(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_responsible: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTodoPriority(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_priority: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(`Form submitted:`);
        console.log(`Todo Seriseno: ${this.state.todo_Serial_no}`);
        console.log(`Todo Description: ${this.state.todo_description}`);
        console.log(`Todo Responsible: ${this.state.todo_responsible}`);
        console.log(`Todo Priority: ${this.state.todo_priority}`);

        const newTodo = {
            todo_Serise_no: this.state.todo_Serial_no,
            todo_description: this.state.todo_description,
            todo_responsible: this.state.todo_responsible,
            todo_priority: this.state.todo_priority,
            todo_completed: this.state.todo_completed
        };

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/todos/add', newTodo)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        this.setState({
            todo_Serial_no: '',
            todo_description: '',
            todo_responsible: '',
            todo_priority: '',
            todo_completed: false
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                <h3>Create New Todo</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                    <div className="form-group"> 
                        <label>Description: </label>
                        <input  type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.todo_description}
                                onChange={this.onChangeTodoDescription}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Responsible: </label>
                        <input 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.todo_responsible}
                                onChange={this.onChangeTodoResponsible}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input  className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="priorityOptions" 
                                    id="priorityLow" 
                                    value="Low"
                                    checked={this.state.todo_priority==='Low'} 
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTodoPriority}
                                    />
                            <label className="form-check-label">Low</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input  className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="priorityOptions" 
                                    id="priorityMedium" 
                                    value="Medium" 
                                    checked={this.state.todo_priority==='Medium'} 
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTodoPriority}
                                    />
                            <label className="form-check-label">Medium</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input  className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="priorityOptions" 
                                    id="priorityHigh" 
                                    value="High" 
                                    checked={this.state.todo_priority==='High'} 
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTodoPriority}
                                    />
                            <label className="form-check-label">High</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Todo" className="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

edit-todo.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class EditTodo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //this.onChangeTodoSerial_no = this.onChangeTodoSerial_no.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTodoDescription = this.onChangeTodoDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTodoResponsible = this.onChangeTodoResponsible.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTodoPriority = this.onChangeTodoPriority.bind(this);
        this.onChangeTodoCompleted = this.onChangeTodoCompleted.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            //todo_Serial_no: '',
            todo_description: '',
            todo_responsible: '',
            todo_priority: '',
            todo_completed: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/'+this.props.match.params.id)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    //todo_Serial_no: response.data.todo_Serial_no,
                    todo_description: response.data.todo_description,
                    todo_responsible: response.data.todo_responsible,
                    todo_priority: response.data.todo_priority,
                    todo_completed: response.data.todo_completed
                })   
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    /*onChangeTodoserialno(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_Serial_no: e.target.value
        });
    }*/

    onChangeTodoDescription(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_description: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTodoResponsible(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_responsible: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTodoPriority(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_priority: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeTodoCompleted(e) {
        this.setState({
            todo_completed: !this.state.todo_completed
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const obj = {
            //todo_Serial_no: this.state.todo_Serial_no,
            todo_description: this.state.todo_description,
            todo_responsible: this.state.todo_responsible,
            todo_priority: this.state.todo_priority,
            todo_completed: this.state.todo_completed
        };
        console.log(obj);
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/todos/update/'+this.props.match.params.id, obj)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        this.props.history.push('/');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3 align="center">Update Todo</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

                    <div className="form-group"> 
                        <label>Description: </label>
                        <input  type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.todo_description}
                                onChange={this.onChangeTodoDescription}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Responsible: </label>
                        <input 
                                type="text" 
                                className="form-control"
                                value={this.state.todo_responsible}
                                onChange={this.onChangeTodoResponsible}
                                />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input  className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="priorityOptions" 
                                    id="priorityLow" 
                                    value="Low"
                                    checked={this.state.todo_priority==='Low'} 
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTodoPriority}
                                    />
                            <label className="form-check-label">Low</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input  className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="priorityOptions" 
                                    id="priorityMedium" 
                                    value="Medium" 
                                    checked={this.state.todo_priority==='Medium'} 
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTodoPriority}
                                    />
                            <label className="form-check-label">Medium</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input  className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="priorityOptions" 
                                    id="priorityHigh" 
                                    value="High" 
                                    checked={this.state.todo_priority==='High'} 
                                    onChange={this.onChangeTodoPriority}
                                    />
                            <label className="form-check-label">High</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <input  className="form-check-input"
                                id="completedCheckbox"
                                type="checkbox"
                                name="completedCheckbox"
                                onChange={this.onChangeTodoCompleted}
                                checked={this.state.todo_completed}
                                value={this.state.todo_completed}
                                />
                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="completedCheckbox">
                            Completed
                        </label>                        
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update Todo" className="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

todos-list.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Todo = props => (
    <tr>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_Serial_no}</td>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_description}</td>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_responsible}</td>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_priority}</td>
        <td>
            <Link to={"/edit/"+props.todo._id}>Edit</Link>
        </td>
    </tr>
)

export default class TodosList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {todos: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ todos: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    componentDidUpdate()
    {

        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ todos: response.data });
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }



    todoList() {
        return this.state.todos.map(function(currentTodo, i){
            return <Todo todo={currentTodo} key={i} />;
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Todos List</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }} >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Serial no</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Responsible</th>
                            <th>Priority</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.todoList() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

server.js

I have a problem here, I don't know how to connect with MySQL database. please help me out I'm new and learning here.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const todoRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 4000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'system',
    database: 'db'
});

connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }
});
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
todoRoutes.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
    connection.query("Select * from todos",
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err)
            }
            console.log(result);
            res.send({
                data: result
            });
        }
    )

});
 app.get('/todos/:id', function (req, res) {
     connection.query('select * from todos where Serial_no=?', [req.params.id], function (error, results) {
         if (error) throw error;
        res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
 });
 app.post('/todos/add', (req, res) => {
     const Serial_no = req.body.Serial_no;
     const todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
     const todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
     const todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
     const todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;
     console.log(Serial_no, todo_description, todo_responsible, todo_priority, todo_completed);
     const insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO todos (todo_description,todo_responsible,todo_priority,todo_completed) VALUES (?)';
     connection.query(insertQuery, [[todo_description, todo_responsible, todo_priority, todo_completed]],
         (err, result) => {
             if (err) {
                 res.send(err)
             }

             else
                 res.status(200).send({
                     data: result, message: 'data have been added sucessfully.'
                 });
             }
     )
 });
/*
app.post('/edit', (req, res) => {
    connection.query('UPDATE todos SET todo_completed = ? WHERE Serial_no = ?', [todo_completed], function (error, results, fields) {
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err)
            }
            console.log(result);
            res.send({
                 data: result, message: 'data have been updated sucessfully.'
            });
        }
    )

}
});
*/
app.post('/todos/update/:id',(req, res) => {
    const Serial_no = req.body.Serial_no;
    const todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
    const todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
    const todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
    const todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;
    console.log(Serial_no, todo_description, todo_responsible, todo_priority, todo_completed);
    connection.query('UPDATE todos SET todo_completed = ? WHERE Serial_no = ?', [todo_completed, Serial_no],
    //const updateQuery =('UPDATE todos SET todo_description = ?, todo_responsible = ?, todo_priority = ?, todo_completed = ? WHERE Serial_no = ?',
    //connection.query(updateQuery,{Serial_no: "", todo_description: "",todo_responsible: "",todo_priority: "",todo_completed: ""},
    //connection.query('UPDATE todos SET todo_description = ?, todo_responsible = ?, todo_priority = ?, todo_completed = ? WHERE Serial_no = ? :Serial_no',
                     //{Serial_no: Serial_no, todo_description: todo_description,todo_responsible: todo_responsible,todo_priority: todo_priority,todo_completed: todo_completed});
    //connection.query(updateQuery, [[Serial_no,todo_description, todo_responsible, todo_priority, todo_completed]],
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        }

        else
            res.status(200).send({
                data: result, message: 'data have been updated sucessfully.'
            });
        }
)
});

app.use('/todos', todoRoutes);
app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

In backend, I have also tried to divide the program in three parts 
1.config
=> connection.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var connection = require('./backend/config/connection');
var routes = require('./backend/controllers/routes');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

connection.init();
routes.configure(app);
function Connection() {
  this.pool = null;

  this.init = function() {
    this.pool = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 10,
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'system',
      database: 'db'
    });
  };

  this.acquire = function(callback) {
    this.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      callback(err, connection);
    });
  };
}

module.exports = new Connection();
```

2.controllers
=> routes.js

```
var todo = require('../models/todo');

module.exports = {
  configure: function(app) {
    app.get('/todo',function(req,res) {
      todo.get(res);
    });
    app.get('/todo/:id',function(req,res) {
      todo.getByID(req.params.id,res);
    });
    app.post('/todo',function(req,res) {
      todo.create(req.body,res);
    });
    app.put('/todo/:id',function(req,res) {
      todo.update(req.body.name,req.params.id,res);
    });
    app.delete('/todo/:id',function(req,res) {
      todo.delete(req.params.id,res);
    });
  }
};
```

3.models
=> todo.js

```
var connection = require ('../config/connection');

function Todo() {
  this.get = function(res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err,con) {
      con.query('select * from todos', function(err,result) {
        con.release();
        res.send(result);
        console.log("Get successful");
      });
    });
  };
  this.getByID = function(id,res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err,con) {
      con.query('select * from todos where Serial_no = ?', id, function(err,result) {
        con.release();
        res.send(result);
        console.log("Get by ID successful");
      });
    });
  };
  this.create = function(todo,res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err,con) {
      con.query('insert into todos set ?', todo, function(err,result) {
        con.release();
        if (err) {
          res.send({status:1, message:'TODO creation fail'});
        } else {
          res.send({status:0, message:'TODO create success'});
          console.log("Post successful");
        }
      });
    });
  };
  this.update = function(todo,id,res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err,con) {
      con.query('update todos set todo_completed = ? where Serial_no = ?', [todo, id], function(err,result) {
        con.release();
        if (err) {
          res.send({status:1, message:'TODO update fail'});
        } else {
          res.send({status:0, message:'TODO update success'});
          console.log("Put successful");
        }
      });
    });
  };
  this.delete = function(id,res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err,con) {
      con.query('delete from todos where Serial_no = ?', id, function(err,result) {
        con.release();
        if (err) {
          res.send({status:1, message:'TODO delete fail'});
        } else {
          res.send({status:0, message:'TODO delete success'});
          console.log("Delete successful");
        }
      });
    });
  };
};

module.exports = new Todo();
```

Comment: What is the problem? are you getting errors? please if you have error add theme to the question, or explain more about the issue you are facing.

Comment: I think he is looking for git repo of solution :)

Comment: please look at the code and guide me where I have done mistakes. I have so many errors 1. when I use server.js then my update MySQL query doesn't work and I don't know how to fetch the data on my webpage. @Ma'mounothman

Comment: I don't have any problem in app.js, create-todo.cpmopnent.js, edit-todo.cpmopnent.js and todo-list.component.js. I have problem in server.js and how to make its module @DeepKakkar

Comment: Does the mysql database exist? Did you grant that user access on the db? Did you create the mysql tables required? Your console should be telling you something.